# Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap Firebase Android

Tags: android, json, firebase

Me sorprende tener este fallo por que me pasa nada mas inicializar la app y nunca me había pasado. El fallo puede ser algo del json? dejo el código donde se produce el fallo

```
public void datos() {

    navMenuName.setText( user.getDisplayName() );
    navMenuEmail.setText( user.getEmail() );

    if (user.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
        Glide.with( this ).load( user.getPhotoUrl() ).into( navMenuImage );
    }

    email = navMenuEmail.getText().toString();
    names = navMenuName.getText().toString();
    uiD = user.getUid();

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = database.getReference();

    database.getReference().child( USERS_NODE ).child( uiD ).addListenerForSingleValueEvent( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            users = dataSnapshot.getValue( User.class );    // FALLO

            if (users == null) {
                users = new User( names, email, photoUrl );

                databaseReference.child( USERS_NODE ).child( uiD ).setValue( users );
            }

            Glide.with( context ).load( users.getAvatar() ).into( navMenuImage );
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    } );
}
```

Logcat

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source:106)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzku.zza(Unknown Source:125)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zzb(Unknown Source:196)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzkt.zza(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source:10)
    at com.lujan.confirmaciones.MainActivity$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:267)
    at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source:7)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source:13)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source:71)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
```

Clase User

```
public class User {


private String name;
private String email;
private String avatar;
private List<String> events;
private String vote;


//Constructor


public User() {
    this.events = new ArrayList<>();
}

public User(List<String> events) {
    this.events = events;
}

public User(String name, String email, String avatar) {

    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.avatar = avatar;
    this.events = new ArrayList<>();
}

public User(String name, String email, String avatar, List<String> events) {

    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.avatar = avatar;
    this.events = events;

}

public User(String name, String email, String avatar, String vote) {

    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.avatar = avatar;
    this.events = new ArrayList<>();
    this.vote = vote;

}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
    this.avatar = avatar;
}

public void setEvents(List<String> events) {
    this.events = events;
}

public void setVote() {
    this.vote = vote;
}

//  GET´S


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getAvatar() {
    return avatar;
}

public List<String> getevents() {
    return events;
}

public String getvote() {
    return vote;
}
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu clase `User` y uno de los nodos de Firebase al cual intentas mapear a objeto `User`?

Comment: Está todo lleno de `Unknown Source`... tienes problemas con la referencia a la que intentas acceder (no existe) o bien ni siquiera estás conectada a Firebase.

Comment: @Andrespengineer Puesto la clase User.

Comment: @A.Cedano siempre me ha funcionado y no he tocado nada de esta clase por eso es un error que me ha sorprendido, te pongo la bbdd

Comment: Al entrar con otro movil no me da ese fallo, que sentido puede tener?

Comment: Pues si desde otro móvil te funciona es posible que en alguna parte haya algo relativo a la autentificación en `Firebase` que en el otro dispositivo está ya hecho y en el nuevo no... Puede ser una cuestión de `Firebase` en general, o de ese nodo, que puede estar restringido a ciertos usuarios o que puede tener autorizado solamente aquel usuario con el que te funciona. Lo cierto es que los `Unknown Source...` apuntan a un problema desde el principio con la referencia de `Firebase` o con ese nodo en particular.

Comment: por favor muestra la estructura de User en la base de datos. Suena que hay una incompatibilidad con el modelo que tienes en Java.

Comment: @jirungaray añadido, el problema es que con algunos moviles arranca bien la app y con otros no como comenté

Comment: Comentar que con el emulador que me funcionaba ha dejado de funcionar y a tener el mismo fallo aquí comentado

Answer (score 1):

El problema que estas teniendo es con el atributo `List<String> events` , por como esta configurado firebase mapea todos las colecciones como Mapas, a las que les asigna una estructura llave:valor.
Para resolver este problema tienes las siguientes alternativas:

1. Utilizar `Map<String,String>` para events
2. (No probado) Iterar en el setter de events sobre los valores del mapa que se recibe y guardarlos en la lista a mano.

Ejemplo:

```
  public void setEvents(Map<String,String> mapa){
    this.events = new LinkedList();
    for(String valor: mapa.values()){
    this.events.add(valor);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para traer la lista de eventos desde tu firebase podes hacer lo siguiente

este onDataChange viene de la referencia `child("Events").addValueEventListener(...`

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
    for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        list.add(child.getValue(User.class));
    }
}
```

Para traer datos desde firebase con un bean en este caso User.class no te hace falta tener declarados constructores con datos, un simple constructor vacio estaria bien

```
public User() {

}
```

Comment: Nada, el mismo fallo haciéndolo de esta manera